# NTFS filesystem not being read on my Windows Dualboot

Tags: windows, partitioning, disk

I formatted my entire disk except my Windows partition and made two partitions. One for Ubuntu and one for personal stuff.

My Ubuntu partition is in ext4 so Windows doesn't recognize it. But my other partition is NTFS. But, Windows doesn't recognize that either. I'm running 12.04 along with Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: Still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the partition in Windows and see if Ubuntu reads it.

Comment: Well,thats my last resort but I have a lot of data on that partition and it will take hours to back it up on my external hard drive.

Comment: I had a similar problem. At one time when I formatted the drive in Windows I could only see it in Windows and vice versa. Couldn't figure out a consistent pattern.